# estimate kaplan meier survival curves from coxph for factor reference group in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have fitted a coxph model in R using the following code:

```
surv.a <- coxph(Surv(cum.goodp, dlq.next) ~ winter + spring + summer + strata(section) + cluster(itemcode), data = nr.sample)
```

The model incorporates seasonal effects via dummy variables for winter, spring, summer relative to fall.  Fall is the reference group/season.  Using the "surv.a" item above, I would like to obtain KM survival curves for each season.  I know that I can fix the covariates to create a "newdata" item to be used for kaplan meier estimation, like so:

```
spring.a <- data.frame(summer =0, spring =1, winter=0, section = c('D', 'N', 'S'))
spring.surv.a <- survfit(surv.a, newdata = spring.a, type = 'kaplan-meier')
summer.a <- data.frame(summer=1, spring=0, winter=0, section = c('D', 'N', 'S') )
summer.surv.a <- survfit(surv.a, newdata = summer.a, type = 'kaplan-meier')
winter.a <- data.frame(summer=0, spring=0, winter=1, section = c('D', 'N', 'S') )
winter.surv.a <- survfit(surv.a, newdata = winter.a, type = 'kaplan-meier')
```

My problem is that since, by definition, only three seasons can be accounted for at a time without creating a singular data matrix, it seems KM estimates can only be arrived at for three of the four seasons. My question is this: is there a way to use the estimates of the other seasons (winter, fall, spring) to "back-out" KM estimates for the reference group fall?  Or perhaps another method of obtaining these reference group KM estimates?  Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks so much.

Comment: How about with fall.a <- data.frame(summer=0, spring=0, winter=0, section = c('D', 'N', 'S') ) ?